# how to keep a gap of 5 seconds in every batch of request in c#

Tags: c#

I have a written an application in c# that receives a request from another application and sends a request to an external broker via HTTP. broker accepts only 40 requests at a time. so I have a config where I mention the count. Broker is asking us to send 40 requests in one batch and another 40 in another batch but there should be a gap of 5 seconds. **my question is how to call a method at a specific time**. Presently 2 batches each with 40 requests go at the same time. My Present code looks like this. I need some idea how can I handle this .. Help will be highly appreciated. thanks.

```
if (requestBatchesByAccount.TryGetValue(locate.account, out BatchRequestInfo batch) == false)
{
    batch = new BatchRequestInfo();
}

batch.locates.Add(locate);
requestBatchesByAccount[locate.account] = batch;

if (batch.locates.Count == maxBatchSize)
{                      
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RequestStockLoanBatch), batch);
    requestBatchesByAccount.Remove(locate.account);  
}
```

Comment: Perhaps only one thread should be handling requests. As it would be meaningless to have more than one thread contesting in a (likely) locking mechanism for each 5 second interval.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add the following code before calling the method:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

And add `async` to the method that contains it.

Comment: sorry .. Udi Y i didn't get you.. you mean I should remove  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RequestStockLoanBatch), batch);
Can you please explain little more

Comment: I meant to add the delay before invoking `QueueUserWorkItem`, but now I understand it's not good enough because makes a delay even when not needed.

Comment: So now I suggest to keep `DateTime.Now` in a variable, and each time subtract the last time. If it's less than 5 secs, then make a delay of the difference time with `Task.Delay`. This will invoke `QueueUserWorkItem` after 5 secs.